# System.BadImageFormat Exception with Android Oreo 8.1 on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

any help with the following error would be much appreciated.

I am trying to build and deploy the Android version of my Xamarin Forms app.

I have the following environment/packages applied:

- .NetStandard 2.0.
- Xamarin.Android support libraries 27.0.2.
- Target Android version 8.1.
- Compile using Android version 8.1.
- SDK linked only.

Every time I try to deploy the app in Release mode it throws the following exception:

System.BadImageFormatException: Could not resolve field token 0x04000033, due to: Could not load type of field MyApp.Droid.MainApplication+<>c:<>9__1_0' (1) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. assembly:System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type: member: assembly:MyApp.Droid.dll type:<>c member:

Whenever I change the linking option to none, the app runs without a problem. So initially I tried lots of ways to try to skip linking assemblies (e.g. I've added a full list of assemblies for skipping on the Android Options page, and used [Android.Runtime.Preserve]), but none of these have worked. Its preferable to keep the linking option to SDK as this keeps the .apk at a reasonable size.

Another point - the app runs without a problem on Android 8.0 but again, I'd like to run it on Android 8.1 if possible.

Would anyone know how to overcome this error?

Many thanks.

Comment: newer 8.1 ROMs are 64 bit. So compile the App as ARM64